# Print the image's name, not the url in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's the views code(Carrierwave handles the upload):

```
- @photos.each do |photo|
  = photo.image
```

This shows  this:
/uploads/photo/image/5/my_pic.jpg

I want only the file from this line like:
"my_pic.jpg"

If there's no method for this, it would be good to create one,
which cuts it at the last slash.

Edit:
The question was, "How to print only the filename? Not the whole url."

Comment: how did you declare your uploader in the model?

Comment: have you tried `filename` or `basename + extension`? I suppose it would be `photo.image.filename`

Comment: photo.image.filename returns null, photo.image.basename nomethod error

Comment: mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

in photo.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- @photos.each do |photo|
  = File.basename(photo.image)
```

Comment: `File.basename(photo.image.to_s)`
this way it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I once had issues because the api for local storage and fog were different.

I ended up creating a getter:

```
def image_filename
  self[:image]
end
```